# How to check if single user can submit only x no. of requests per quarter?

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to calculate the a single requester can submit maximum 20 requests a quarter. He can create max 20 case per quarter.

- How we can achieve this using OOTB or using Trigger ?
- How we can put the validations around it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, from a single account if you want to create max 20 cases, then use `Entitlement` properly.

So, for every quarter you will create new Entitlement record for that Account and define `Cases Per Entitlement` = 20

In that scenario, you do not need to put additional validation rule. Salesforce will take care based on Entitlement Configuration.

Also, think about leveraging `Entitlement Contact`

[image: Entitlement]